# nth-of-type takes the whole group of icons

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with the property called nth-of-type.
Basically i want to put each icon in a different color, but when i change the coordinates from the css the property nth-of-type takes the whole group of icons, and i don't get why..
[nexus site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVJZu.png)

HTML:

```html
    <article class="main">
                <div id="img-wrapper">
                    <img src="media/images/nexus.jpeg" alt="Schema nexus" />
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-music"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-video"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-cloud"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-book"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-tumblr"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="far fa-lightbulb"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-balance-scale"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-users"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-graduation-cap"></i></a>
                </div>
            </article>
```

CSS:

```css
    #img-wrapper i:hover{
        color           : white;
    }

    #img-wrapper i:nth-of-type(1){
        top             : 40px;
        bottom          : ;
        left            : ;
        right           : 240px;
    }

    #img-wrapper i:nth-of-type(2){
        top             : ;
        bottom          : ;
        left            : ;
        right           : ;
    }
    #img-wrapper i:nth-of-type(3){
        top             : ;
        bottom          : ;
        left            : ;
        right           : ;
    }
    #img-wrapper i:nth-of-type(4){
        top             : ;
        bottom          : ;
        left            : ;
        right           : ;
    }
```

Comment: Each `<i>` is the first within its parent `<a>`. Something like this should work: `#img-wrapper a:nth-of-type(2) i`

Comment: Why not make different color classes or used IDs instead? Either way you'll want to apply those or your nth-of-type to the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Because the icons are not siblings, but the anchor tags are, you can target the anchor tags by nth-of-type and style their icon children like so:

```
#img-wrapper a:nth-of-type(1) i
```